# Javascript String Splicing does not seem to work

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, algorithm, local-storage

im trying to save Expanded/Collapsed states of my Bootstrap Collapses.

Im saving it in the LocalStorage and Reading it out of it.

```
$(".content-accordion-content").each(function (index) {
                console.log(index, $(this).attr("id"));
                $(this).on("show.bs.collapse", function () {
                    var expandedCollapses = localStorage.getItem("ExpandedCollapses");
                    if (expandedCollapses !== undefined && expandedCollapses !== null && expandedCollapses !== "") {
                        expandedCollapses = expandedCollapses + "|" + $(this).attr("id");
                    }
                    else {
                        expandedCollapses = $(this).attr("id");
                    }
                    localStorage.setItem("ExpandedCollapses", expandedCollapses);
                })
                $(this).on("hide.bs.collapse", function () {
                    var expandedCollapses = localStorage.getItem("ExpandedCollapses");
                    if (expandedCollapses !== undefined && expandedCollapses !== null) {
                        if (!expandedCollapses.includes("|") && expandedCollapses.includes($(this).attr("id")))
                            expandedCollapses = "";
                        else {
                            var ecArr = expandedCollapses.split("|");
                            expandedCollapses = ecArr.splice(ecArr.indexOf($(this).attr("id")), 1).join("|");
                        }
                        localStorage.setItem("ExpandedCollapses", expandedCollapses);
                        console.log(expandedCollapses,$(this).attr("id"));
                    }
                })
            });
```

It seems to work, but sometimes it removes multiple Entries from the Array.
For Example
I Open Authors then Open Books then Open Videos. the string Looks like this "Authors|Books|Videos"
If i close Books now, its only "Authors"
Can someone help me unstuck my brain?

Comment: Can you provide some inputs, actual outputs and expected outputs so we have something to work with?

Comment: `splice()` changes the original array and returns the deleted items, so this is not what you expect it to be: `expandedCollapses = ecArr.splice(ecArr.indexOf($(this).attr("id")), 1).join("|");`

Comment: you should do the splice and then assign the value back: `ecArr.splice(ecArr.indexOf($(this).attr("id")), 1); expandedCollapses = ecArr.join("|");`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoops, found it. I joined the outcome of the .splice() method.
which turns out the be wrong.
this here fixed my code

```
var ecArr = expandedCollapses.split("|");
ecArr.splice(ecArr.indexOf($(this).attr("id")), 1);
expandedCollapses = ecArr.join("|");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` instead of `splice`.

Makes the process a little simpler because we don't actually **need** to know the index of the value we want to remove.

```js
let currentValue = "";
function toggleValue(_value) {
   let splitValue = currentValue.split("|").filter(_=>_);
   // split by '|'
   // as well as filter out falsy string values i.e. ""
   if (splitValue.includes(_value)) {
    // check if the array includes the value
    // we can use includes because we arent checking for complex types
    splitValue = splitValue.filter(v => v !== _value);
    // filter out the value that already exists in the array
   } else {
    splitValue.push(_value);
    // we know the value doesn't exist so we can safely push it to the array
   }
   const newValue = splitValue.join("|");
   // join the array with '|'
   updateValue(newValue);
}

//#region Ignore This
function updateValue(_value) {
  currentValue = _value;
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = currentValue;
}
//#endregion
```

```html
<button onclick="toggleValue('author')">Toggle Author</button>
<button onclick="toggleValue('books')">Toggle Books</button>
<button onclick="toggleValue('videos')">Toggle Videos</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```